# Rewritecond does not check for second condition

Tags: mod-rewrite, redirect, httpd.conf

I use the following rewritecond but when i'm accessing the server with a browser from 10.40.62.13 it still uses the standard homepage.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{http:iv-remote-address} ^((172\.30|10\.89)\.(.*)\.(.*))|((10)\.(40)\.(62)\.(13))$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /applications.html [PT,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} !^10\.40\.62\.13
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^172\.30\.10\.89
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/redirect_page\.html$
RewriteRule \.html$ /redirect_page.html [R=302,L]
```

Comment: Thx for the answer but can you explain how it will redirect a address like 172.30.10.20 or 10.89.10.20 because I don't see no check for this range?

Comment: it will only redirect when you access the server from 10.40.62.13, for multiple ip's we need to workaround.. updated the answer